# Passing a column in dataframe to function using Rccp

Tags: r, rcpp

This is just a very basic knowledge for a lot of people, but this is my first time to use Rccp package.  I'd like to pass a column in a dataframe to a function using Rccp, which I can manipulate data in the column.  Thank you.

```
library(Rcpp)

df <- data.frame(Temp = c(25, 25, 85, 85, 125, 125, 125), Val =c(1.03, 1.06, 1.56,1.75,2, 1.85, 1.90), type=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

arr<- df$Val

last <- length(arr)

cppFunction('int index(int arr[], int low, int high){

            int max = arr[low];

            int i;

            for (i = low; i <= high; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] > max)
                max = arr[i];
            }
            return i;
}')

ind <- index(0,last-1,arr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please look e.g. at

- the DataFrame example in the RcppExamples package
- several other questions where on the SO site
- the Rcpp Gallery.

The easiest example from the aforementioned package is just:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List DataFrameExample(const DataFrame & DF) {

    // access each column by name
    IntegerVector a = DF["a"];
    CharacterVector b = DF["b"];
    DateVector c = DF["c"];

    // do something
    a[2] = 42;
    b[1] = "foo";
    c[0] = c[0] + 7; // move up a week

    // create a new data frame
    DataFrame NDF = DataFrame::create(Named("a")=a,
                                      Named("b")=b,
                                      Named("c")=c);

    // and return old and new in list
    return List::create(Named("origDataFrame") = DF,
                        Named("newDataFrame") = NDF);
}
```

Comment: I want to use Rcpp to increase a performance, but it looks like it is slower in my case.  I used a stopwatch timer to record  a time to run with Rcpp was 7 minutes 31 seconds and for R was only 24 seconds.  I want to extract a first maximum in an array (multiple array in a file) that increase then decrease then increase again.  For R used something like this min(which(diff(Array) < 0)) with a few condition, and for Rcpp I used for loop.  I expected it faster, but it was slower.